# EPPlus: character '&' in cell become "&amp;" after saving XLSX file

Tags: escaping, xlsx, epplus, ampersand

I export data to XLSX file using DTS task. Strings of data contain '&' character. After that I open the file using EPPlus, make some corrections, and save it. As a result, instead of the symbol '&' it save strings "&*amp;"'*'. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What "corrections" are you making? Can you show some code?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and posted an [appropriate bug](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15092) on [the official CodePlex project page](https://epplus.codeplex.com/). Right now it is in Resolved state, so it seems that right now it is enough just to update to the latest stable version of EpPlus. If it's not, please provide some additional details and code.